# The unitary time-evolution in the interation picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, time-evolution

I'm currently consuming a course on QFT where we need to define the unitary time-evolution to get the time evolution of the wave function in the interaction picture:

$\hat{U}(t_1,t_0) = \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}_0t_1\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}(t_1-t_0)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}_0t_0\right)$ .

Now one can show that this operator follows a Schrödinger equation by simply taking the derivative to time:

$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\hat{U}(t,t_0) = \hat{H}_1^I(t)\hat{U}(t,t_0)$ .

Where $\hat{H}_1^I$ is the perturbation to our free-field Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_0$.

Now I started wondering whether $\hat{U}(t_1,t_0)$ shouldn't also follow a Heisenberg equation since it's an operator.

I believe it shouldn't since $\hat{U}(t_1,t_0)$ gives a unitairy time-evolution which is a transformation, while the Heisenberg equation applies to observables. I was woundering if someone could confirm my reasoning or disprove it?

Comment: If $t_1$ and $t_0$ are constants, then $\hat{U}(t_1,t_0)$ is the operator evaluated at those particular instants, not a function. Think about the function $\sin(x)$ and the function evaluated at $x_0$ $\sin(x)|_{x=x_0}=\sin(x_0)$

Comment: Yes but if I were to take $t_1$ as my variable, then it might follow some equation governing the time-evolution. That it follows Schrödinger can be proven. For the Heisenberg-case this doesn't work (I wouldn't know how to take the commutator of $\hat{H_1^I}$ and $\hat{H_0}$). My reasoning for this is that the Heisenberg-equation only applies to observables, not the transformation (what the  $\hat{U}(t_1,t_0)$ in principle is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes,* OP is right. The Heisenberg evolution equation in the [interaction picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture#Time-evolution_equations_in_the_interaction_picture) applies to an operator $A_I(t)$, that depends on a single moment of time $t$. On the other hand, the evolution operator $\hat{U}(t_f,t_i)$ depends in principle on the whole intermediate time interval $[t_i,t_f]$, and is in particular not a local operator of a single time.

Comment: Ok, that might explain my conceptual problems upon trying to derive the Heisenberg-like equation. Thanks!

Now I was woundering if it was purely because of the fact that $\hat{U}(t_f,t_i)$ is depending on the interval $[t_i,t_f]$. Or also because of the fact that it is a transformation and Heisenberg doesn't apply to transformations ?

Comment: @Nick: Well, I'm not sure what class of transformations you allow, but a sufficiently well-behaved local transformation operator that is only associated with a single time should satisfy the Heisenberg evolution equation.

Comment: @Nick: An other way to see that is that the evolution operator have to be expressed as a time ordered function of the perturbation hamiltonian.

Comment: Why would they violate Heisenberg if I'd have a time-ordered product ?

Comment: @Nick: I guess you are essentially asking how to handle a product of two operators $\ldots B_I(t_2)A_I(t_1)\ldots$ inserted at different times $t_2>t_1$? Note that operators inserted at different times in the interaction picture is usually of the form $\ldots B_I(t_2)U_I(t_2;t_1)A_I(t_1)\ldots$.

Comment: The question was more aimed at the comment of @Trimok Since I'm not quite able to follow his line of reasoning. He suggets that by seeing the time-evolution operator as a time-ordered product (what it actually is), it's also easy to show that $\hat{U}(t_f,t_i)$ doesn't follow Heisenberg. Your argument makes sence to me Qmechanic but the more views the better :).

Comment: @Nick : From the  expansion of the time-ordered form of the evolution operator $U(t,t_0) = T (e^{-i \int_{t_0}^t du H_{int}(u)})$, in integrals containing powers of $H_{int}$, one see clearly that $i\frac{\partial U(t,t_0)}{\partial t} = H_{int}(t) U(t,t_0)$. The fact that there is only one term $H_{int}(t)$ left (and not a commutator with $H_{int}(t)$) is related to the fact, that,  each term in the expansion begins like  $\int_{t_1}^t H_{int}(t_1) dt_1 \int_{t_2}^{t_1}$.......... So, if you make the $t$ partial derivative, you will get a $H_{int}(t)$ term at the left.

Comment: Ah okay, so that's actually the Schrödinger-equation that had been written down in my origional question?

Comment: @Nick : Yes. Be careful, it is a partial derivative. (Minor remark : if you want your message appears in the mail box of somebody, you have to do a @ (for instance @Trimok). Sometimes it is automatic, but not in this case.)